# Windows not installing after resetting the laptop

Tags: windows, reset

So i just reset my Acer laptop, but the windows is not installing after the reset. The screen just kept on showing this message,

"The computer restarted unexpectedly or encounter an unexpected error. Windows installating cannot proceed. To install windows, click "OK" to restart the computer, and then restart the installation".

I did click "OK" but to no avail. I tried it many times but its not working. Can anyone please help me on this? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find how to boot your laptop to enter the recovery mode to restore your windows, usually, it done by pressing F8 or F10 or F12 depends on the laptop model. It might help you. 
Good Luck